# ruby on rails with scoped routes and default_locale: search.google error 5xx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

ruby on rails app with scoped routes and default_locale

Problem: If I navigate to root_url https://www.example.com the page loads in the default locale, but search.google can't find this page and produces an error 5xx with no further explanations.

It does find and index pages like https://www.example.com/de or https://www.example.com/en or any other locale - even non existing ones.

Is there a way I can get google to accept the page https://www.example.com so it does index it, or at least to get it to re-interpret it as https://www.example.com/de (as this is the default_locale)?

Comment: But don't just put 5xx, but the exact error you're receiving. Isn't the same receiving a 500 (which probably you'll find the exact error in the rails app logs) as a 501 or 502 that could have to do more with your server setup. Also, how do you know google is getting a 5xx? could you share more about that?

Comment: Alter Lagos, that IS the exact error I am getting from google search console: URL is not on Google: Indexing errors: "Failed: Server error (5xx)". As I wrote, the page loads perfectly fine in any browser, there is no error in rails app logs. The error is from googlebot smartphone and desktop, when indexing the page.